# How do I sum of the first n rows of another column in bash

Tags: awk

For example given

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

I want to sum up the numbers in the second column and create a new column with it. The new column is 4, 9 (4+5), and 15 (4+5+6)

```
1 4 4
2 5 9
3 6 15
```

Comment: What have you tried? It can be done in bash, but other languages might be better suited for such a problem. Any particular dependency for a shell script for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to mention your efforts which you have put in order to solve your problems as we all are here to learn. kindly add your efforts in code tags in your post.

Comment: I have tried using awk to extract the second column and loop through each number while storing the sum in a variable. Then sed to put the result in the old file. This is extremely slow since Im working on a large file and I was wondering if there is a faster way with one command. Im new to bash so im not comfortable with the commands yet

Comment: @JohnWard, then please add clear picture of your requirements in your post by editing it and  let us know. Did you try my command btw?

Comment: Following the advise of always posting what you have tried, along with any errors (e.g. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) -- your questions will be much better received (and you will receive fewer downvotes `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following if you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print $0,$2;prev=$2;next} {print $0,$2+prev;prev+=$2}'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'FNR==1{print $0,$2;prev=$2;next} {prev+=$2;print $0,prev}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                    ##Startig awk program here.
FNR==1{                  ##Checking condition if line is first line then do following.
  print $0,$2            ##Printing current line with 2nd field here.
  prev=$2                ##Creating variable prev whose value is 2nd field of current line.
  next                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                        ##Closing block for FNR condition here.
{                        ##Starting new block here.
  prev+=$2               ##Adding $2 value to prev variable value here.
  print $0,prev          ##Printing current line and prev variable here.
}' Input_file            ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***PS:*** Welcome to SO, you need to mention your efforts which you have put in order to solve your problems as we all are here to learn.

Comment: Providing both forms is a very instructional way to do it. First with straight-forward logic flow in the general expression but a few keystrokes longer, a slightly more condensed version as well.

Comment: This is just what Im looking for. Thank you. Would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: @JohnWard, added detailed manner explanation, please check it and let me know if any queries.

Answer (score 1):

this is more idiomatic

```
$ awk '{print $0, s+=$2}' file

1 4 4
2 5 9
3 6 15
```

print the current line and the value s, which is incremented with second field, in other words is a rolling sum.

this can be golfed into the following if all values are positive (so no chance of summing to 0), but perhaps too cryptic.

```
$ awk '$3=s+=$2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk..

```
$ cat john_ward.txt
1 4
2 5
3 6
$ awk ' {$(NF+1)=s+=$NF}1 ' john_ward.txt
1 4 4
2 5 9
3 6 15
$
```